# Trying to query a PFRelation for a specific user in Parse

Tags: ios, parsing, pfquery, pfrelation

I'm trying to query a PFRelation of the current user of the app to load a table view showing all of the users friends. Each user is saved under a class called "User" when they first use the app and once they add a friend that friend is added to the column "friendsRelation" for the user. I'm using this code i got got from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331572/parse-how-do-i-query-using-pfrelation-when-i-just-have-pfuser/%22link%22) and nothing is returned from the query.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"friendsRelation" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred fetching friends");
    }

    else {
        [self.friends addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
PFRelation *relation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"friendsRelation"];
PFQuery *query = [relation query];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
     // results contains all friends of current user
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not query the `PFUser` table, so you cannot use `[query whereKey:@"friendsRelation" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];` to query the `User` table, since the `friendsRelation` does not contain any `PFUser` objects but `User` objects. Just get the `User` object which represent for current user and use it to query the relation.

Comment: If I query the current user I get this for the friendsRelation: friendsRelation = "<PFRelation: 0x9ce82c0>(<00000000>.(null) -> _User)"; How do I pull the list of friends from this?

Answer (score 1):

To Query the Users table don't use

```
[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
```

Use instead

```
[PFUser query];
```

Only use the first if you have created your own "User" table and at this point if you checked the Data-browser you will see two different tables both called "User".