# Adding constraints to a PFQuery with objects from a PFRelation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, pfquery

I am using a PFQueryTableViewController and I am querying PFObjects called Group. These groups objects all have relations to a User PFObject. I want to add constraints to this query by querying only the groups that have relations containing the current user. How do I add constraints to a query by only returning objects that contain the current user in the relation?

```
            -(PFQuery *)queryForTable{
            PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
    //Users is a relation
            [query whereKey:@"Users" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
//This crashes the app
//I need to return only objects with current user in the users relation
            return query;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: If there is anything I can clarify on just ask

Comment: "Relation" as in "PFRelation", or a pointer? Or array of pointers, rather. Your code should work on an array of pointers.

Comment: Its a PFRElation object

Comment: it is the same. this answer shows your exact use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331572/parse-how-do-i-query-using-pfrelation-when-i-just-have-pfuser